# Prism: Match language types not starting with dot or : character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am extending [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) with a custom language and I want to highlight types (int, float, bool).

I want to match strings that do not start with a dot or a : symbol.

I already tried with regex alone but couldn't make it work, so I probably must use [Prism's lookbehind parameter](http://prismjs.com/extending.html#language-definitions) but I am having trouble making that work.

```
float JsValue.float
float JsValue:float(float testFloat)
int JsValue.int
int JsValue:int(int testInt)
```

The regex below captures everything which is not what I want.

```
/\b(int|bool|float)\b/
```

The regex below (thanks to [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)) captures what I want but also captures the "(" character after function name.

```
/(?:^|[^:.])\b(int|bool|float)\b/
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you use `/(^|[^:.])\b(int|bool|float)\b/` with `lookbehind: true`?

Comment: Your regex looks good (could be even simpler: `/[^:.](int|bool|float)\b/`). Have you actually tried using this regex with lookbehind set to true? I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference you linked to](http://prismjs.com/extending.html#language-definitions) states:

> **lookbehind:**
>   This option mitigates JavaScript’s lack of lookbehind. **When set to `true`, the first capturing group in the regex pattern is discarded** when matching this token, so it effectively behaves as if it was lookbehind.

Actually, it is an implementation of the PCRE [`\K` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3F%3C%3Dpattern)-%5CK).

So, use

```
/(^|[^:.])\b(int|bool|float)\b/
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

where `(^|[^:.])` is a *capturing* group. Set `lookbehind: true`, too.